# how to build umbrella chart with exact dependency helm chart version in requirements.yaml file

Tags: nexus, kubernetes-helm, nexus3

We have Micro services application which has different `helm` charts for each MS, and there is umbrella chart which adds all these charts and create an integrated chart for simple deployment purpose, we use Nexus3 as a helm repo.
In umbrella chart `requirements.yaml` dependencies are added with version, repository.
When we specify exact chart version in `requirements.yaml`, sometimes it fails to find that chart in nexus repo, though it actually exists. After some investigation found that it looks for the version in `index.yaml` of that nexus repo, if required version is not same as like the one in `index.yaml` file it fails.
`index.yaml` contains latest version always, but what if we want to work with different version than latest one ? how can we fix this ?
Below is the snippet of `requirements.yaml` file

`dependencies:
  - name: ms1
    version: "1.3.0"
    repository: http://user:passwd@nexus_host:8081/repository/helm_chart_repo/ms1
  - name: ms2
    version: "1.3.0"
    repository: http://user:passwd@nexus_host:8081/repository/helm_chart_repo/ms2
  - name: ms3
    version: "1.2.0"
    repository: http://user:passwd@nexus_host:8081/repository/helm_chart_repo/ms3
  - name: ms4
    version: "1.3.1"
    repository: http://user:passwd@nexus_host:8081/repository/helm_chart_repo/ms4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the required version of the Helm Chart exists in the repository, but does not exist in `index.yaml`, then it means that your `index.yaml` is not correct. It should contain all the versions that are in the repository.

Check if `helm repo index <directory>` is always performed after new version is added.

Comment: you are right, some how we are missing all the other versions from ```index.yaml``` except latest one always though we use ```helm repo index <chartdir> --url <remote repo> --merge index.yaml```

Comment: Found that issue is with our automation code :(.
Logic is something like this, download ```index.yaml``` from remote, merge it with local one and upload it back to remote.
but there was issues with downloading ```index.yaml``` from remote, which was causing always to just upload new file to remote.
After fixing the download code , it is working as expected (```index.yaml``` has multiple versions now in remote)